Prove that in Hopf bundle $p:S^3\to S^2$, every two fibers are linked with linking number one.
Regard $S^2$ as copmlex projective plane.  $$S^3= \{(z_0,z_1)\in \mathbb{C}^2\mid z_0\overline{z_0}+z_1\overline{z_1}=1\}$$$$p: S^3\to\mathbb{C}P^1,\quad p(z_1,z_2)=[z_1,z_2].$$
Suppose that $z_1\neq 0,z_1^\prime\neq 0$, and $[z_1,z_2], [z_1^\prime,z_2^\prime]\in\mathbb{C}P^1$, then
$$p^{-1}([z_1,z_2])=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}^2\ |\ a=\frac{z_1}{z_2}b, |a|^2+|b|^2=1 \},$$
$$p^{-1}([z_1^\prime,z_2^\prime])=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}^2\ |\ a=\frac{z_1^\prime}{z_2^\prime}b, |a|^2+|b|^2=1 \}.$$
how can I prove that these two circles are linked in $S^3$ ?
Also, how can I visualize it intuitively? Would someone provide some pictures or videos?

What definition/characterizations of two circles being linked are available to you?
